# HornetQ: Configure the number of consumers

Tags: java, hornetq, consumer

I know that the number of Consumers can be modified with:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "X")
```

where "X" is the number of consumers.

But is there another way of changing them? Because I want to get that number from a File (I read a **.properties File**, and then I set the number of consumers.

I'm using hornetq 2.2.14.Final with JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Comment: I don't think there's a way to change it.

Comment: Maybe through the .xml configuration file, is it possible?

Comment: through the xml you could try using the property notations using $... there are a few other cases using that on the WF config.